# "errorMessage": "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'", Python Selenium on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda

I am trying to run selenium python on AWS Lambda. But when I try to execute it from the console, I get the following error.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'",
  "errorType": "OSError",
  "requestId": "820cf57b-8fd7-4ee4-82b9-6f93178ec148",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/handler.py\", line 34, in crawler\n    browser = uc.Chrome(options=options, data_dir='/tmp')\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py\", line 237, in __init__\n    patcher = Patcher(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/patcher.py\", line 66, in __init__\n    os.makedirs(self.data_path, exist_ok=True)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/os.py\", line 215, in makedirs\n    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/os.py\", line 215, in makedirs\n    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/os.py\", line 215, in makedirs\n    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/os.py\", line 225, in makedirs\n    mkdir(name, mode)\n"
  ]
}
```

I looked up the solution as suggested by Mark B.

[AWS Lambda function returns "errorMessage": "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73394593/aws-lambda-function-returns-errormessage-errno-30-read-only-file-system)

Here are the runtime versions I am using

```
Python: v3.9
Selenium: v4.6.1
undetected-chrome-driver: v3.1.7
```

I changed the code in my script file to insert it into the temp folder

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
browser = uc.Chrome(options=options, data_dir='/tmp')
```

But I see the same error on the AWS console logs. I was hoping you guys could help me figure out the solution for this. Thanks in advance!

Here is the selenium script that I am trying to run on AWS Lambda.

```
import json
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException

import time
import json
import os

def responseGenerator(body, message, statusCode):
    response = {}
    response['statusCode'] = statusCode
    response['body'] = json.dumps({
        'message': message,
        'body': body
    })
    return response 

def crawler(event, context):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = False
    browser = uc.Chrome(options=options, data_dir='/tmp')
    # ... enterprise application logic that I can't really put here!!
    return responseGenerator("End of crawler execution", None, 205)
```

It is running perfectly in my local machine. But failing there!

Comment: What is the full lambda code allowing for reproduction of the issue?

Comment: I have provided a code snippet. please take a look

Comment: Is this answer of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73394694/7012917