# Langchain document loaders give read only file system error on AWS lambda while loading the document

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, langchain

I am trying to load a file from S3 bucket using AWS Lambda using `langchain` document loaders.

I first tried using `S3FileLoader` when it gave the read-only file error.

So I tried downloading the docx file first from the S3 bucket and then used the specific document loader `UnstructuredWordDocumentLoader` as it was the Word document I uploaded. However it still gave the same error.

Eventually I want to load any type of document in S3 bucket and generate embeddings to store in an Opensearch vector database.

Also if I try to deploy my Lambda function with docker using image `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11` I get a error:

```
FileNotFoundError: soffice command was not found. Please install libreoffice
```

Here is my code:

```
from langchain_community.document_loaders import S3FileLoader from langchain_community.document_loaders import UnstructuredWordDocumentLoader

#first approach
#loader = S3FileLoader(s3_bucket, s3_key)
#docs = loader.load()

#second approach
s3.download_file(s3_bucket, s3_key, f"/tmp/{s3_key}")

with open(f"/tmp/{s3_key}", "rb") as f:
loader = UnstructuredWordDocumentLoader(f"/tmp/{s3_key}")
docs = loader.load()
```

The error is:

> [ERROR] OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051' Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/task/aws_lambda_powertools/logging/logger.py", line 449, in decorate return lambda_handler(event, context, *args, **kwargs) File "/var/task/lambda_handler.py", line 54, in handler docs = loader.load() File "/var/task/langchain_community/document_loaders/unstructured.py", line 87, in load elements = self._get_elements() File "/var/task/langchain_community/document_loaders/word_document.py", line 124, in _get_elements return partition_docx(filename=self.file_path, **self.unstructured_kwargs) File "/var/task/unstructured/documents/elements.py", line 526, in wrapper elements = func(*args, **kwargs) File "/var/task/unstructured/file_utils/filetype.py", line 619, in wrapper elements = func(*args, **kwargs) File "/var/task/unstructured/file_utils/filetype.py", line 574, in wrapper elements = func(*args, **kwargs) File "/var/task/unstructured/chunking/init.py", line 69, in wrapper elements = func(*args, **kwargs) File "/var/task/unstructured/partition/docx.py", line 228, in partition_docx return list(elements) File "/var/task/unstructured/partition/lang.py", line 397, in apply_lang_metadata elements = list(elements) File "/var/task/unstructured/partition/docx.py", line 305, in _iter_document_elements yield from self._iter_paragraph_elements(block_item) File "/var/task/unstructured/partition/docx.py", line 541, in _iter_paragraph_elements yield from self._classify_paragraph_to_element(item) File "/var/task/unstructured/partition/docx.py", line 361, in _classify_paragraph_to_element TextSubCls = self._parse_paragraph_text_for_element_type(paragraph) File "/var/task/unstructured/partition/docx.py", line 868, in _parse_paragraph_text_for_element_type if is_possible_narrative_text(text): File "/var/task/unstructured/partition/text_type.py", line 78, in is_possible_narrative_text if exceeds_cap_ratio(text, threshold=cap_threshold): File "/var/task/unstructured/partition/text_type.py", line 274, in exceeds_cap_ratio if sentence_count(text, 3) > 1: File "/var/task/unstructured/partition/text_type.py", line 223, in sentence_count sentences = sent_tokenize(text) File "/var/task/unstructured/nlp/tokenize.py", line 29, in sent_tokenize _download_nltk_package_if_not_present(package_category="tokenizers", package_name="punkt") File "/var/task/unstructured/nlp/tokenize.py", line 23, in _download_nltk_package_if_not_present nltk.download(package_name) File "/var/task/nltk/downloader.py", line 777, in download for msg in self.incr_download(info_or_id, download_dir, force): File "/var/task/nltk/downloader.py", line 642, in incr_download yield from self._download_package(info, download_dir, force) File "/var/task/nltk/downloader.py", line 699, in _download_package os.makedirs(download_dir) File "", line 215, in makedirs File "", line 225, in makedirs

Comment: When using an AWS Lambda function, you are only permitted to write files to the `/tmp/` directory. The error says `Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'`, which means that the langchain code is attempting to write to a location that is _not_ in `/tmp/`.

Comment: See also: ["errorMessage": "\[Errno 30\] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'", Python Selenium on AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75774683/174777)

Comment: Thanks John for the reply .......the problem is how do I make the langchain document loaders to write to "/tmp" file ?